# I cannot install Ubuntu with macOS Mojave

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, macosx

I’m using Mojave and created a partition for Ubuntu. I chose FAT MS-DOS as I do not have ext4 in the list. I’m using Disk utility: should I follow a different way? The partition is created but after rebooting, while trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive, the installation starts (initial questions about language, keyboard) but then it stops as no device can be found to install Ubuntu. It seems only the USB drive is found and the system warns that Ubuntu can’t be installed in 4Gb (that is the size of my USB drive!).

Answer (score 0):

Your mojave installation is formatted using APFS, which Ubuntu is currently unable to read. Ubuntu can only read drives formatted as NTFS (Windows), HFS/HFS+ (Mac OS Extended), EXT2, EXT3, EXT4, FAT, and FAT32 (MS-DOS). To successfully install ubuntu alongside an APFS formatted macOS installation (High Sierra and Mojave), you must choose the something else choice and locate your partition you created via Disk Utility. When you select the FAT partition, click the button on the bottom labeled change and format that as ext4.